# Why isn't Linux terminal letting me type after I've pasted something?

Tags: networking, command-line

I'm a Linux noob and I'm absolutely struggling. One of my projects for my "internship" is to set Ubuntu as the domain controller. The OS of the machine is Ubuntu 22.04.

I'm following along to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT6O-TfJ41g and I'm at minute 2:10 in the video. I paste my IP address where I'm supposed to but I can't type the FQDN (am I supposed to type what the guy in the video typed? Or do I type my own? If so, how to I find my machine's FQDN. The OS is Ubuntu 22.04). When i pasted my IP address and the FQDN from the video, the FQDN went to the line underneath the IP address, how do I get it on one line?

I also want to know how to create extra line spaces if needed. Example: Just like I added a line in between this section and the above section, how do I do that on the Linux terminal?

I'm working with my neighbor on this but he went out of town for 3 weeks and I don't want to bother him with unneccessary questions about concepts that I'm sure are fairly easy. I'm essentially doing this on my own for now! Help please.

Comment: `vi` is notoriously hard for beginners to work with. Use `nano` instead.

Comment: Don't type the FQDN that the guy in the video typed. Use your own local IP address, and use your own FQDN. If you don't have one, use only the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so that video tutorial is using an editor called "vi" - this can be a difficult editor to use at first.

He is editing the "hosts" file which lives in /etc, this is a file that is used to map an IP Address to a host name, you'd typically use DNS for this but it's a handy way to map addresses locally.

You wouldn't use the FQDN from the video, you would use your own which you can get with "hostname --fqdn" in a Terminal window.

Within vi, if you press the "i" button that will put you into "Input" mode, like the guy in the video.  This allows you to enter text, create new lines, etc within vi.

Once you have finished, press the "ESC" key and then ":wq" to write the file and quit vi.

There are numerous vi tutorials online if needed.